# Is there a way to connect react to local supabase

Tags: supabase

I just followed the supabase documentation to create a local environment in supabase. The problem I have is that already having a project in react, is there a way for me to start using that environment? I have configured my client.js with the environments given by supabase in local environment.
ie:

- `REACT_APP_SUPABASE_LOCAL_URL > API URL: http://localhost:54321`

  ```
  import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
  const supabaseUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_LOCAL_URL : process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL;
  const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY_LOCAL : process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

  export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
  ```

And my other question is when I point to the db that I already have in production in the local environment, it only brought me the tables but not the data from them. Is there any possibility?

Comment: For question 1: What is happening when you query a table in the react project? Does it try to fetch something at all? Do you get any error codes?
For question 2: When you do a supabase db remote commit it only takes the tables, policies, functions etc. It does not copy data from the production environment.
Normally you would write a seed.sql with the data you want to be inserted in the database when you start the supabase locally. This way you can break it and do a supabase db reset.

Comment: hey i already fix the problem to connect the db. somehow the variable localhost was not getting recognized from .env. about the seed mmm i had to put ctegories data and roles by hand XD.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use something like [pgdump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) e.g. see the [Supabase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/overview#migrating-between-projects) or you can seed some fake data in your local Supabase project with something like [SeedAI](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/seedai).

To dump your data, you can use `supabase db dump --data-only --db-url=your@postgres.db.url`, see https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-db-dump . The output from this you can put in your local `supabase/seed.sql` file.

Comment: hi, yes already did the dump and connect the supabase to my front in react. But i had not succes seeding the db with the data from production

Comment: You can use `supabase db dump --data-only --db-url=your@postgres.db.url`, see https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-db-dump . The output from this you can put in your local `supabase/seed.sql` file.